# Trying to get a specific temperature range while also keeping in range of other two variables

Tags: python, text-files

```
min_desired =int(input("Min. Desired Temp.: "))
max_desired = int(input("Man. Desired Temp.: "))

def desired(min_desired,max_desired):
    holder= []
    count = 0
    total = 0
    with open('C:/Users/amaya/OneDrive/Desktop/Weather_final.txt','r') as weather_contents:
        weather = weather_contents.readlines()
        for lines in weather:
            #Use map to convert values on each line to float and to list
            column = list(map(float, lines.strip().split()))
            holder.append(column)

        print(holder)
        for x in holder:
            print(x)
            if x >= min_desired and x <= max_desired:
                if humidity < 70 and humidity > 40:
                    if wind < 12:
                            count +=1
                            total += x
                            avg = (total/ count)
                            print(count)
                            print (avg)

print(desired(min_desired, max_desired))
```

I'm aware that 'humidity' and 'wind' are undefined and that what I've tried might be completely wrong. I'm stumped on how to get the first column, which would be 'Temp' that needs to be in a specific range.

ex. min temp = 60
    max temp = 85

while taking into consideration 2 pre-set conditions
humidity must be  between 70 and 40 & wind must be lower than 12

Thanks in advance for all the help!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiJYI.png)

Comment: What are the column names in your text file?

Comment: always put data as text, not image - Python can't read data from image, so we can't test this code.

Comment: you have data in lists so instead of `x`, `humidity` and `wind` you should use `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Not only will this make parsing your textfile much easier, but pandas dataframes have methods to help you select data based on any criteria you want. Using pandas, your code can be made much simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
weather = pd.read_csv('weather.txt', sep=" ", names=['Temperature', 'Humidity', 'Wind'])
```

To select data where wind < 12 and 40 < humidity < 70:

```
subset = weather.loc[(weather['Wind']>12) & (weather['Humidity']>40) & (weather['Humidity']<70)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would use `pandas` because it would need simpler code and it has many other useful functions.

But here I will show how it could be done without `pandas` - but I don't have your data to test it.

I would use one `for`-loop and then I could directly convert `column` (or rather `row`) to variables

```
temp, humidity, wind = column
```

---

```
# --- functions ---

def desired(min_desired,max_desired):
    #data  = []
    count = 0
    total = 0
    with open('C:/Users/amaya/OneDrive/Desktop/Weather_final.txt','r') as weather_contents:
        for line in weather_contents:
            row = list(map(float, line.strip().split()))
            #data.append(row)
            temp, humidity, wind = row
            if min_desired <= temp <= max_desired and 40 < humidity < 70 and wind < 12:
                count += 1
                total += temp

        print('count:', count)
        if count != 0:
            print('avg:', total/count) # don't divide by zero

# --- main ---

min_desired = int(input("Min. Desired Temp.: "))
max_desired = int(input("Man. Desired Temp.: "))

# without `print()` if you use `print()` inside function
desired(min_desired, max_desired)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time